# Create dump file using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, export, import, oracle-sql-developer

I think I'm missing a simple point, but I couldn't find a way to use Oracle export (exp/expdp) and Oracle import (ipm/impdp) with Oracle SQL Developer (version 1.5.5)? Is there a way for it?

If possible, how can I make it point different Oracle export or import utilities (which are located different places and have different versions i.e. 10g , 11g)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, Import/Export and Data Pump are command-line-only types of tools.  But if you really wanted to use that functionality from within SQL Developer (or SQL Plus), Data Pump uses the built-in **DBMS_DATAPUMP** and **DBMS_METADATA** packages.  You should be able to call those packages directly, so I would start there.  There's documentation available in the 
[Oracle® Database PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/toc.htm) on both of them ([DBMS_METADATA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_metada.htm#i1015856) and [DBMS_DATAPUMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_datpmp.htm#i1007277)).

Comment: What about `Tools > Database Export` in SQL Developer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10665344/